# Classic website to Mobile website content mapping

Tags: mobile, content

When a visitor with a mobile device clicks on a link to www.website.com/product we can redirect them to m.website.com/product. This page has content and a layout best suited to smart phone users.

When a mobile device clicks on a link to www.website.com/services and that page does not exist at our m.website.com, where do we direct them to?

Do we:

- Redirect them to (what we, internally, define as) a relevant mobile site page?
- Redirect them to (what we, internally, define as) a relevant mobile site page, *and* include a "View original page on the Classic website" link?
- In the instance where there is a one-to-many relationship (as opposed to a one-to-one) between a Classic website page and a Mobile website page, we redirect them to a "Where you looking for?" index page that lists (what we define as) relevant mobile site pages?
- ...or, something else?

What are the standard practices here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, designing for the viewport instead of the device has a lot of benefits. Having two separate websites can create maintenance issues, which can impact UX (consider the two sites diverging with the non-mobile website being updated more often - it has happened quite a bit).

If you have one site and design for the viewport, you will eliminate many of the issues you've discussed. There are many ways to do this, but [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), [Skeleton Framework](http://getskeleton.com/), and many more employ this technology ([responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design)).

I'd suggest looking at some more resources on responsive design, including Ethan Marcotte's awesomely short [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design), or take a look at [Responsive web design Vs Separate Website for Mobile](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/responsive-web-design-vs-separate-website-for-mobile) here on se.ux.

Answer (score 2):

The standard practice is to make sure that every single page has a mobile-optimized counterpart because you don't know how visitors will be referred to your site (e.g., from an e-mail read on a mobile device but sent from a desktop). You also must make sure that the mobile version of the site doesn't refer to un-optimized pages.

Now, in case such a situation arises after all, you need to check the referral and act accordingly:

- If the person is referred from your mobile website, they're expecting to continue seeing the mobile version of the site. Therefore, you should present them with a placeholder page informing them that the content isn't available for mobile & offering a redirect to the desktop version.
- If the referral is from an external source, you can show the desktop version right away as there's no explicit expectation of it (*people do expect it implicitly because it's 2012*).

However, in both cases, you will also need to decide what to do when the visitor continues the session and tries to access some content that does have a mobile version. The problem is that you need to provide a consistent browsing experience and switching between mobile & desktop versions is the opposite of that.

As you can see, not having all pages ready for mobile consumption results in a rather convoluted UX. Thus, do your best to prevent it.