# Any Research on User Experience Perceptions of Native Apps vs Web or Hybrid Apps

Tags: usability, mobile, web-app, research, native-app

My organization is looking at developing mobile applications, we have a wealth of web development resources. There are many factors to consider in making the decision of how to develop this application such as Cost(s), platform support, performance, and maintainability.

But, **I have not found any research that actually backs up the assumptions that users prefer the experience of a native app over a hybrid mobile web app** (A hybrid app is a HTML5 app distributed in an embedded web view using PhoneGap, etc.).

Some [people assert](http://www.gartner.com/newsroom/id/2429815) that native apps are more performant and have a better user experience, but why? **Have there been any user surveys or analytics that indicate this user preference towards native?**

Comment: When using PhoneGap, you essentially end up with a native app. So as far as the user is concerned, there is no perceptual different between what you are calling native vs. hybrid. It's purely a development-side decision at that point.

Comment: @DA01 PhoneGap would love you to believe that, but there are definite differences between them.  That is part of the reason that both LinkedIn and Facebook have abandoned web-apps being wrapped as native apps.

Comment: @JohnGB there are certainly differences that can become obvious based on the particular type of app one is trying to build, but not necessarily generic differences across the board. I don't think one can generically say 'PhoneGap apps are better/worse than Objective-C apps' as it's going to be entirely dependent on the context of the particular app.

Comment: @DA01 Every development choice is a tradeoff.  PhoneGap is a better *development* choice in some situations, but I have yet to see a case when it is better UX wise.  If you know of one, please share it with me.

Comment: @sirtimbly could you clarify what, exactly, you are comparing? Is it only Native vs. a web-view (Which doesn't necessarily have to be built with PhoneGap). Or are you comparing HTML5-based apps (such as PhoneGap) with native? Or all three?

Comment: @JohnGB I'm saying it's not a *better* option any more than it's a *poorer* option in terms of UX. Both options can have great UX experiences and both can have terrible UX experiences.--but, that said, I'm also not entirely sure what we're comparing. It sounds like we're talking web-app vs. native which is a little different than HTML5/phonegap vs. objective-C

Comment: @you786 yes, I think it wouldn't be true if there was a web view being used, which makes it more of what I call a 'web app'. But if there isn't a webview, then the user experiences the PhoneGap pretty much the same way as a native app. Both are purchased in the store, installed the same, and used the same.

Comment: I think the terminology is getting confusing here. PhoneGap apps must use a subclass of WebView on Android apps. Otherwise there is no place to run the javascript that PhoneGap requires.

Comment: @you786 yes, another good point. It definitely shows how these terms are quite complex/confusing and don't necessarily have definitions that everyone agrees upon.

Comment: @JohnGB: you are correct that FB abandoned the HTML5 app, but that doesn't mean it's impossible to re-create the same UX. Please see: http://vimeo.com/55486684

Comment: @VincentvanScherpenseel It's never going to be exactly the same experience due to the more buggy nature of HTML5 apps and lower speed.  But those aside, it's more about development issues as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @JohnGB, I don't think it's a valid argument when you add "it's more about development issues" :) It's more complicated to do it right, that's correct. But it's not impossible.

Comment: @VincentvanScherpenseel It is impossible to have the same speed as native, and for the other parts, if it's more complicated, it costs more, and takes longer.  Those are two of the biggest development issues.

Comment: @JohnGB, I agree that HTML5 apps don't get the same speed as native at the moment, but it's ever improving. On the other hand: web is native on platforms such as Tizen or BTG. I agree that if it's more complicated it costs more, but you can't just ignore the fact that having to do native apps for multiple platform at the same time increases costs enormously as well. Android and iOS are both very big platforms, and depending on your market you may want to add a third platform (and I don't expect the status quo to remain as it is today).

Comment: @VincentvanScherpenseel Speaking from experience, it's cheaper and faster to develop native than html if you just want iOS and Android.  Most of my mobile dev experience has been html dev, so I'm not coming from an idealistic perspective.  That may change in the future, but it's not the case now.

Comment: @JohnGB, I have exactly the opposite experience :) I guess it also comes down to repetition and what you're familiar with. In any case, the mobile future is interesting.

Comment: Just be aware that we are in a mobile app bubble now...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there have been formal studies demonstrating that as users become increasingly familiar with mobile devices, they shift increasingly toward using native apps.<sup>4</sup>  This trend is likely a combination of three factors:

- **People prefer the familiar.** If people know of a site or app that's likely to address their needs, they're more likely to use that known source than to search.<sup>3</sup> Users trust known resources because they're more reliable: information needs are four times as likely *not* to be addressed when using generic search than when using direct re-access of a known source.<sup>3</sup>
- **Mobile users bookmark differently.** Bookmarks in mobile browsers are used sparingly,<sup>4</sup> instead mobile users "bookmark" by downloading the native app.<sup>1,4</sup>
- **Native apps offer superior interaction.**

  - They can be used offline, which makes them faster to open.<sup>2</sup> It can also make their performance faster in some cases by allowing them to store information locally and only synchronize with the server after the user is done using the app.
  - They allow the user to use device-specific hand gestures.  Android and iOS are gradually developing different conventions for interaction, and a native app responds the way its user expects.
  - They have access to device-specific functions such as geolocation and accelerometers (although with HTML5, web apps are gradually gaining access to these functions as well).

<sub>[[1] Bales, Elizabeth, Timothy Sohn, and Vidya Setlur. “Planning, Apps, and the High-end Smartphone: Exploring the Landscape of Modern Cross-device Reaccess.” In Proceedings of the 9th International Conference on Pervasive Computing, 1–18. San Francisco, USA: Springer-Verlag, 2011.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2021977)</sub>

<sub>[[2] Caspar Ryan and Atish Gonsalves. 2005. The effect of context and application type on mobile usability: an empirical study. In Proceedings of the Twenty-eighth Australasian conference on Computer Science - Volume 38 (ACSC '05), Vladimir Estivill-Castro (Ed.), Vol. 38. Australian Computer Society, Inc., Darlinghurst, Australia, Australia, 115-124.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1082174)</sub>

<sub>[[3] Heimonen, T. (2009). “Information Needs and Practices of Active Mobile Internet Users.” In Proceedings of the 6th International Conference on Mobile Technology, Application Systems, 50:1–50:8. Mobility  ’09. New York, NY, USA](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1710035.1710085)</sub>

<sub>[[4] Tossell, C., Kortum, P., Rahmati, A, Shepard, C., & Zhong, L. (2012). “Characterizing Web Use on Smartphones.” In Proceedings of the 2012 ACM Annual Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems, 2769–2778. CHI  ’12. New York, NY, USA: ACM.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2208676)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, great work. "Native apps offer superior interaction." was the point I'm most concerned with backing up. Reference 2 seems the most applicable to that.

Comment: @sirtimbly I'd say Reference 2 is the worst of the group.  In the spreadsheet where I take notes on articles, I wrote for Reference 2 `"This paper doesn't really say much of anything.  It may have been the first to look at native vs. non-native apps."`  Reference 4 is a great paper with a lot of information about how and why people use native apps.  If you're mainly interested in my third bullet point, there's some more evidence to support it in [Mobile First](http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first) if I remember correctly.

Comment: @sirtimbly I'm still a bit unclear as to what you are specifically wanting to compare. 3nafish's answer is great, but is talking about web apps (meaning apps that exist on a web server that you view through a web browser). However, I think you were asking about compiled native apps built using HTML5 via PhoneGap. Note that those are different things.

Comment: @DA01 Actually, Reference 4 is all about native app usage, Reference 2 compares native and non-native apps, and References 3 and 1 establish a historic context of mobile usage patterns, demonstrating the root of the need for native apps.  Phrases in my response such as "used offline" and "device specific" should make it quite clear that I am writing about the UX advantages of native apps over web apps.

Comment: @3nafish I understand you are comparing Native Apps with Web Apps. I'm not critiquing your answer (as it's a good one) but trying to get clarification from the OP on exactly what they want. I *think* (but am not sure) that the OP was wanting to compare Native Apps (coded in a native language) with Native Apps (coded with HTML5 and PhoneGap). Again, it's confusing as people are using different definitions for the various terms throughout this Q&A. (In other words, it appears that there are many varying definitions of 'web app' floating around in these answers which maybe confusing to some).

Comment: You are correct, my intention is to compare native apps coded in native language vs native apps viewed in a webview compiled by PhoneGap. Both of you seem to understand my question, I have decided to call all PhoneGap apps "Hybrid Apps" based on my research.

Comment: @sirtimbly when you say 'viewed in a webview' do you mean that the app is still loading an external web app via a client-server model? Or are you simply saying it's a standalone native app--but built with phonegap? If the latter, 3nafish's answer doesn't directly address that.

Comment: @DA01 I think the confusion comes from ambiguity in the question title, "Native Apps vs Web or Hybrid Apps," which implies two separate comparisons {1} native vs. web (which I compared) and {2} native vs. hybrid (which I ignored as not being a good fit for this site because from the user's standpoint they're essentially the same, just made differently).

Comment: @3nafish yes! Exactly! I think we're on the exact same page there. It is important to distinguish between those.

Comment: Reference 2 is also a bit outdated in that it cites that mobile browsers don't provide location context, whereas now they do (albeit by the virtue of the device providing location services, and those that are far more accurate than simply inferring location by IP address (via GeoMind or some other geo-ip database)).

Comment: @GrahamHerrli: Great answer, thanks. But I'm asking myself if it is still true? I read much about the mess on smartphones because of too many apps, and the trend goes more back to web-apps since nowdays there is much more possible in ways of interactions (don't have a link, just came across articles multiple times in the past month's). Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 7):

**Look and feel depends on how you design the web-app**.  You can design it to look exactly the same as a native app, but you have to choose which native you want it to be like (unless you build multiple web-apps that is).  The result is that most web-apps try go for something that is usable by both iOS and Android but looks like neither - which is why people sometimes comment on the looks.

I have been working on a product that was designed as a web-app initially, but after months of usability testing and feedback from users, is now going to change to a native app.  I can't give you any formal research, just what I have found in UX testing and development.

## UX issues

1. Most **people don't understand what a web-app is**.  Even after explaining it to users, the most common question I get is "so which app store do I get it from".
2. There are so many variations between browsers, browser versions, and phones, that it makes it close to **impossible to develop a stable web-app** that runs on all devices that you expect it to run on.  No matter how much testing we have done on many devices, we have had endless issues with web-apps out in the wild, that we have not had on native iOS and Android apps.
3. Web-app frameworks are definitely **slower** than native apps.  They are improving speed wise, but they are never going to compete.
4. Web-apps are **unavailable when offline** - even as a basic version.

## Development issues

1. Web-app frameworks are improving fast, which often means many **rewrites** and constant updates to keep up with the improvements.
2. You **need a broader skill set** to work with web-apps than you do with native.  For example on Android, you need Java.  But for our web-app, we needed: html, css, sass, javascript, coffeescript, and Sencha Touch.  The result being that anyone working on the web-app had to firstly be comfortable with far more languages and tools, and that it was longer to train anyone.

Comment: Your issue 4 under UX issues is not always true. A web-app in this case simply means running using javascript and HTML, not necessarily that it requires the internet. You may develop a web-app if you already know Javascript and HTML and you don't want to learn Objective-C or Java, for example.

Comment: @you786 can you give me an example of a mobile web-app (what we're talking about), that doesn't need an internet connection?

Comment: As much as I'd love to have web apps be a viable option (I guess I'm biased in that for being web focused myself professionally), they're so far off it's not funny. The rendering of the visual UI, in the smoothness of transitions but also the responsiveness of everything, it's not there. Same situation on the desktop, but it's better.

Comment: @JohnGB many web apps will use a appcache. I'm rusty on this, but I believe on iOS this is enabled for stuff you put on the home screen that has the proper meta tags. It'll show you old data, just like a native app would, when offline. But with a GUI. Check http://blog.forecast.io/its-not-a-web-app-its-an-app-you-install-from-the-web/

Comment: @JohnGB http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/01/18/my-first-mobile-game-in-html-with-phonegap-build/ It's an HTML game that was made into a "mobile web-app". I haven't played it but I assume an internet connection is not necessary.

Comment: @you786 You still need an internet connection to open that app, it's just cached, so that once you disconnect you're okay.  That's like saying you don't need an internet connection for a website because you can cache it.

Comment: @JohnGB Many PhoneGap apps have the HTML and JS files stored locally in the app file (.apk for Android) and the WebView loads them from local storage.

Comment: @you786 That then isn't a web-app, it's native app that happened to have been generated from HTML and JS.

Comment: @JohnGB Not according to the UX SE tag: "A web app is an application that uses technologies such as Javascript, CSS, and HTML5 and is executed in a web browser. Developers release their applications as web apps because of the larger flexibility of the format. The application can be run directly from a website, or, **if it uses the HTML 5 Offline Application Cache and Web Storage, can be downloaded and installed locally, for offline use**"

Comment: I think we're using a mix of ill-defined terms here. Web vs. hybrid vs. native. A web app certainly tends to have a 'generic' UI across platforms. A PhoneGap app, however, can certainly use native elements specific to each device. While a fully native app only uses the native elements for the device it's written for.

Comment: @you786 let's not turn this into a discussion thread. I'm happy to discuss it in chat. In the mean time the tag was misquoting Wikipedia, and I have corrected that.

Comment: Yes, in reading all the comments, we all are using slightly different definitions. ;) There are 'local apps' (web based applications downloads and stored locally--don't necessarily need a web connection). There are 'web apps' (apps where all or a portion of the UI and data is fetched live from a server). There are HTML5 apps (typically apps created with HTML5/JS/CSS/etc turned into native apps with PhoneGap and the like). And there are native apps (typically Objective C or Java depending on platform). Even then, those are loose definitions.

Comment: Oh, and I suppose we also have 'actual web apps' which you'd launch in the browser (essentially what a web-view in a PhoneGap solution or Native solution would be as well...so again, muddying the waters a bit...)

Comment: @DA01 Nice summary of app types :)

Comment: "sass, javascript, coffeescript, and Sencha Touch" ***FALSE!***

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with some of the points others have made. Unless your app is mostly well designed static content, avoid web apps for mobile. Even in these cases, the app could probably be built to run faster natively in almost the same time. You aren't going to save time using inferior tools. Rarely is this a "tradeoff" type decision, unless you have a bunch of unused expert web developers.

**User Experience**

It's not that Mobile web applications are slightly slower and are only limited by high performance use cases. They are much slower - so much so that it burdens user experience. If you are aiming at features requiring dynamic animation, or even moderate interactivity - "you gonna have a bad time".

One of the best web apps I have seen is here http://forecast.io (visit on a mobile phone) and you can see how slow interacting with even a simple scroll view is. (side note) the developers also mentioned have had a hard time marketing the concept of an app you don't buy from the app store.

One element of good design is tight feedback and user response. Interacting with a touch screen is already difficult for some. Mobile web apps contain acceptable feedback for simple interactions, but anything really beyond hitting a button is going to be inferior to a native app experience, simply because of the amount of time it takes to respond to user touches.

**Development**

1. It is true that for a mobile web app the breadth of knowledge is greater simply because of the fragmentation in web technology. However, developing a good native app requires much more depth of knowledge due to language and framework complexity. That is not to say there are not web apps developed with a good depth of knowledge, but the minimal skills to build an Objective-C or Java application are much greater than HTML + Javascript. Don't kid yourself into thinking more technology names = harder to learn. Also remember, good programmers usually can do good work with any programming technology.
2. When developing web applications you are at the mercy of the framework for device features. if iOS 7 comes out with something cool, you must wait until the framework (phonegap etc) integrates those features (if ever or even possible). Natively, you have access to them day one.
3. Code should very rarely be "rewritten" only refactored. If number of rewrites a year is a metric for you, you have bigger problems. I would expect no difference in time needed to rewrite or refactor either native or web apps, but once again you may be at the mercy of the framework you choose.

**EDIT**

For all you naysayers - benchmarks.
http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/

Comment: "the app could probably be built to run faster natively in almost the same time" there are lots of situations where that isn't true. Examples: if you are supporting many platforms; if frequent updates are necessary/expected; you have limitations on testing team resources, etc.

Comment: Can you back up your assertion "Mobile web apps contain acceptable feedback ... inferior to a native app experience, simply because of the amount of time it takes to respond to user touches." with any evidence?

Comment: @DA01 True, but if you ask any native feature at all, the code is not 1-1, modifications have to made for each platform anyway. Write once run anywhere is rarely true. Also you have to test regardless of programming language... It doesn't go away because you are writing a web app. Server side updates are an advantage, but in that case you are throwing out any hope for native features.

Comment: @sirtimbly I have hard evidence showing the time of feedback loop is longer. I don't have a scientific number that says users like things to happen faster, but generally laggy input = not good. Download that app I link to. You can see the app does everything right, but is just limited by the web platform.

Comment: @JustinMeiners yep, that specific point is true, but in and of itself doesn't mean one type of app is any better/worse that the other. Now, if the particular app depends on native UI components, and access to said components available in each OS release, then yes, I'd say in that particular situation, a native app is the better UX.

Comment: As for 'laggy input' that is certainly an issue, but not necessarily a truism just because an app is a web app. Yes, there will be a lag between the client-server, but if there has to be a client-server relationship, you'd still have that issue with the native app.

Comment: @DA01 You may be able to cheat and get some development benefits, but I see no situation where code written natively would not be superior from a user perspective.

Comment: @DA01 not talking about client-server interaction, obviously there is lag there.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I've used some native apps with horrific UIs and UX. I've used some great web apps with wonderful UIs and UX. Point being that the code, in and of itself, is hardly the deciding factor in whether a UX is good or not.

Comment: @DA01 It is true that you can create good UI, but the code still puts you at distinct disadvantage. That would be like saying making a game for an NES in Java puts you at no UX disadvantage to Assembly. Obviously this an exaggerated case, but the principle still stands true. Also don't extrapolate the argument to the faster language is the better so we should all use assembly. Interpreted Javascript, especially with graphics is much slower on mobile devices than native code. In the future this may not be a problem for most things (such as on desktop), but for now it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the challenge in answering the question is twofold. 1) definitions 2) research.

As for definitions, I'm going to make an assumption that we're comparing:

**Native App** = a self contained application written in native code for the device it's running on.

vs.

**Web App** = an application written with web technologies using a client/server model where the UI is rendered in the client, but all data is fetched and processed on a server.

The second challenge is comparing them. Ideally, one would have written a native app and a web app to be equitable in some fashion so that some form of A/B testing could be performed. I'm not sure if that's done with any regularity (or if at all) for that matter.

When there are both, it's usually two separate experiences altogether. Take Flickr, for example. They have a mobile site (aka 'web app') and they have a native app (aka 'the thing you download from the app store'). The problem is that the UI and functionality between the two is very different, so not easy to simply say one is better than the other.

Ultimately, which is better is going to depend primarily on the type of app you are building.

Comment: Which is better is not dependent on the app type - it's going to be a better experience natively every time. There is hardly any user advantage to accessing an inferior website. Especially if you have to download that webapp from the store.

Comment: @JustinMeiners it's like asking which is better: Java or HTML. In and of themselves, it doesn't matter, as they don't necessarily have a direct correlation to the UI/UX. As for 'inferior website' yes, if the site is always inferior, of course that'd be the poorer choice, but that's assuming the web site is inferior, which is hardly a universal truth (There are plenty of companies that have both web apps and native apps and I often prefer the web version). It all depends.

Comment: The question is supposed to focus on the measurable differences in user experience based on the the runtime the application is in (UIView with native controls vs UIWebView with HTML+CSS+JS). Has anyone measured how users perceive these two different types of app?

Comment: @sirtimbly I think the answer to that is simply 'no'. My answer attempts to provide a theory as to why that is.

Comment: @DA01 They are inferior because of performance, the JS is simply not fast enough to create interactive components that feel good.

Comment: Also, what you are asking in that comment, at least to me, is different than asking about a 'web app'. Again, these terms can be confusing, but it sounds like you are asking about an HTML5+PhoneGap app (compiled to native) more so than an a true web app (an app living on a web server viewed through a UIView or browsers).

Comment: @DA01, client-server interation is not unique to a web app, therefore the difference is the UI, which is inferior.

Comment: @JustinMeiners The native JS handling on iOS, for example, is incredibly robust--combined with CSS transformations, which are native hardware accelerated, and there really is no discernable difference in many cases.

Comment: @DA01 that is simply not true. While a static button or form may be able to pass that off (by running native code in the OS) your own JS will never compare.

Comment: @JustinMeiners agreed about being not unique (again, we're all using really muddy definitions). As for it being 'inferior' unless you have real data, I have to say that is merely your assumption. The UI is dependent on so many things.

Comment: @DA01 this is not a subjective opinion - it takes longer for the OS to provide feedback with the UI, not a little bit, a lot, that is worse for the user, no two ways about it.

Comment: @JustinMeiners are you arguing that a 'button press' interaction has a humanly noticeable performance difference between native and JS based? If so, that has never been my experience.

Comment: @DA01 see scrolling for a good example

Comment: @JustinMeiners *Technically* it's objective. But in terms of UX it's purely subjective. Whether a human can tell the difference between a handful of microseconds is hardly a major factor in deciding a development platform or methodology (See: over-optimization)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'see scrolling'. Can you be specific? My web browser seems to scroll as fine as any native app I have.

Comment: @DA01 I told you , its not a microsecond, its a big amount that is mathematically measurable. Download that app I reference. It sounds like you may be spreading info outside of your knowledge base.

Comment: It's called good experience, not overoptimization. If you want I can code a benchmark, if you don't believe the two are indistinguishable.

Comment: @JustinMeiners yes, like I said, *technically* it's objective. But if a user can't actually tell the difference in use, it's somewhat moot. As for knowledge base, you're coming at it from purely a code optimization point of view--which is just one factor in a big picture of overall UX.

Comment: @JustinMeiners and to be clear, I fully understand the technical aspect you are arguing. Yes, faster code is faster. But there comes a point where the code is 'fast enough' in that anything faster isn't going to give the end user a better experience. My web browser scrolls pages just fine, so I can't see how faster scrolling code benefits me as the end-user.

Comment: @DA01 once again thats native scrolling code, access anything custom written such as the app I linked to.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I'm not sure what specific part of that web site you are referring to, but that would be a an example of a specific feature in a specific app, where choosing a particular technology may very well be a make it or break it decision. But that can't be applied universally in a generic way to all apps. Sometimes it matters, sometimes it doesn't .

Comment: @DA01 it does, moving things around in realtime, a common, generic operation, simply sucks.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I don't know specifically what you are referring to (BTW, if you can take this to chat, please do, alas, I can't see the chat option).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to look good, function quickly and smoothly, native is the best choice. Though there’s extra time and effort involved in coding native apps for each operating system, the benefits in terms of user experience are worth it. Native app behaves much more responsively, providing a full native look and feel – and a better, smoother user experience. Specially with iOS 7 Flat UI, Depth and UI Dynamics, user's expectation from the app have risen. And to keep the user glued to your application, one must provide visual and interaction experience like every other app on that platform. Native Rocks!